# Why do fonts no longer work after upgrading ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv

After a recent upgrade of ConTeXt, ConTeXt can not longer find the OTF and TTF fonts in my `~/.fonts` directory.

Prior to this upgrade, when I ran these three script, it was sufficient to get the fonts working:

```
rm -R ~/.context
mkdir ~/.context
cd ~/.context
wget http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/first-setup.sh
chmod +x first-setup.sh
./first-setup.sh
context --generate
export OSFONTDIR="$HOME/.fonts"
mtxrun --script fonts --reload
```

This time, when running this, `mtxrun --script fonts --reload` displays this message:

> fonts           | names | identifying system font files with suffix otf
>   fonts           | names | adding path from OSFONTDIR: /home/username/.fonts
>   fonts           | names | globbing path /home/username/.fonts/**.otftexlua:  ../../../source/texk/kpathsea/cnf.c:255: kpathsea_cnf_get: Assertion `kpse->program_name' failed.
>   Aborted

When I run `mtxrun --script fonts --list -all --pattern=*`, ConTeXt no longer reports finding any of my fonts in `~/.fonts`. Also, when I try to compile documents, they can no longer use the fonts in `~/.fonts` and my documents are all compiled with ConTeXt's default fonts.

I first encountered this problem with `2012.12.28` and still with `2013.01.02` and `2013.01.10` it is present. Prior to this upgrade, I was using a version from October or November 2012.

Why do my custom OTF and TTF fonts no longer work after upgrading ConTeXt?

Comment: The `~/.fonts` is searched by default. What happens if you do not set `OSFONTDIR`

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: If I do not set `OSFONTDIR`, `mtxrun --script fonts --reload` finishes very quickly with no apparent errors, however, it makes no mention of adding the fonts from `~/.fonts` and furthermore does not add the fonts to ConTeXt. I am using Debian, but installed ConTeXt from `./first-setup.sh` with no options added.

Comment: Can you try with todays `beta 2013.01.09 10:51`? It works here.

Comment: do you mean it literally says `/home/username`  what is $HOME set to?

Comment: I upgraded to `2013.01.10`, but it still does not work. `/home/username` is the same place as `$HOME`.

Comment: Run `source tex/setuptex` after `./first-setup.sh` to include the PATH of the just downloaded version. You're executing a different binary than the one you downloaded.

Comment: Running `source tex/setuptex` while inside the `~/.context` directory still does not solve it. My BASH profile contains `export PATH="/home/username/.context/tex/texmf-linux/bin:$PATH"`, so I never ran this command in the past. If I deleted the entire contents of `~/.context` doesn't that mean the old binaries are gone? I see no binaries in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin` related to ConTeXt.

Comment: I removed all but one font from the `~/.fonts` directory, and found that it installs fine now. I do not remember making any changes to that directory over the past many months. Perhaps ConTeXt now has a problem reading certain fonts? Or perhaps I have a bad font which before was fine, but now creates a problem for ConTeXt?

Comment: `type context` tells you which binary is being invoked. If it's the correct one, it might be a bug in a font or a bug in ConTeXt/LuaTex handling that particular font. First try to identify the font causing the problems. If the font is working correctly with other programs provide the font name, foundry and used version so we can test it. If it turns out to be a bug in ConTeXt or LuaTeX it might make sense to approach the LuaTeX or ConTeXt mailing list.